# XQuery - Get node as string including XML tags

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, xquery

I have an XML column in a table in SQL server 2008R2.
The XML looks like this (simplified example):

```
<root>
   ...
   <Filters>
       <Filter type="a">
          <Patterns>
              <Pattern>bla bla bla</Pattern>
              <Pattern>kuku</Pattern>
          </Patterns>
       </Filter>
       <Filter type="b">
           <Name>Cookie</Name>
       </Filter>
       <Filter type="c">
          <FileTypes>
              <FileType>exe</FileType>
              <FileType>jpg</FileType>
          </FileTypes>
       </Filter>
   </Filters>
   ...
</root>
```

i.e. there can be a lot of filter types defined and every type has unique child elements.
I want to write a query that will return the following string:

```
Filter Type: a
Configuration:
    <Patterns>
        <Pattern>bla bla bla</Pattern>
        <Pattern>kuku</Pattern>
    </Patterns>

Filter Type: b
Configuration:
    <Name>Cookie</Name>

Filter Type: c
Configuration:
    <FileTypes>
        <FileType>exe</FileType>
        <FileType>jpg</FileType>
    </FileTypes>
```

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT
   xmlFiled.query(
     let $nl := "&#10;"
     let $space := "&#32;"
     let $tab := concat($space, $space, $space, $space)
     for $f in /root/.../Filters/Filter 
     return concat("Filter Type: ", $f/@type, $nl, "Configuration:", $nl, $tab, $f/node()[1], $nl)'
     ) AS Filters, 
FROM Table
```

The problem is that the string conversion of $f/node()[1] concatenates the text in all the inner elements of the node without keeping the XML tags, so the result I get is this:

```
Filter Type: a
Configuration:
    bla bla blakuku

Filter Type: b
Configuration:
    Cookie

Filter Type: c
Configuration:
    exejpg
```

Is it possible to achieve what I want in this way?

Comment: You should accept answer that best addresses your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the result you want.

```sql
declare @T table(xmlFiled xml)

insert into @T values
('<root>
   <Filters>
       <Filter type="a">
          <Patterns>
              <Pattern>bla bla bla</Pattern>
              <Pattern>kuku</Pattern>
          </Patterns>
       </Filter>
       <Filter type="b">
           <Name>Cookie</Name>
       </Filter>
       <Filter type="c">
          <FileTypes>
              <FileType>exe</FileType>
              <FileType>jpg</FileType>
          </FileTypes>
       </Filter>
   </Filters>
</root>')

select stuff((
             select char(10)+char(10)+'Filter Type: '+F.N.value('@type', 'char(1)')+char(10)+
                    'Configuration:'+char(10)+space(4),
                    F.N.query('*')
             from T.xmlFiled.nodes('/root/Filters/Filter') as F(N)
             for xml path('')
             ), 1, 2, '')
from @T as T
```

Result:

```
Filter Type: a
Configuration:
    <Patterns><Pattern>bla bla bla</Pattern><Pattern>kuku</Pattern></Patterns>

Filter Type: b
Configuration:
    <Name>Cookie</Name>

Filter Type: c
Configuration:
    <FileTypes><FileType>exe</FileType><FileType>jpg</FileTyp
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I chose not to use xmlField.nodes() and use xmlFields.query(...) because I select values from different columns in the table other than the XML field, so I wanted the FOR clause to be the table itself.